# swift sort by date [NSDate:[String]]

Tags: uitableview, sorting, multidimensional-array, swift2

I am trying to sort by date a multidimensional array because I would like to make a tableview with headers.
In the tableview every header will be a date and below that there will be some events.
First I add some values to my array:

```
import UIKit

extension String{
func toDateTime() -> NSDate{
    //Create Date Formatter
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    //Specify Format of String to Parse
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    //Parse into NSDate
    let dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(self)!

    //Return Parsed Date
    return dateFromString
}
}

var test = [NSDate: [String]]()
test["10-05-2015".toDateTime()] = ["some event", "another event"]
test["11-06-2014".toDateTime()] = ["test event", "test event2", "test event3"]
test["19-03-2013".toDateTime()] = ["super event", "superevent2", "super event3", "super event4"]
```

After that I try:

```
test.sort({ $0.compare($1) == .OrderedDescending})
```

The error from Xcode is:
value of tuple type ... has no member compare

How can I sort by date my array?

Comment: test is Dictionary<NSDate:[String]> , so it is not an Array (ordered collection) but an unordered collection

Answer (score 2):

```
let arr = test.sort { $0.0.compare($1.0) == .OrderedDescending }
print(arr)
/*
[(2015-05-09 22:00:00 +0000, ["some event", "another event"]), (2014-06-10 22:00:00 +0000, ["test event", "test event2", "test event3"]), (2013-03-18 23:00:00 +0000, ["super event", "superevent2", "super event3", "super event4"])]
*/
```

see, that the result is an array of (key, value) pairs, not 'sorted' dictionary

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I am a beginer to Swift. At your opinion, what is the best practise to fill up a tableview with dates sorted?

Comment: @Mic following some Cocoa or Cocoa touch tutorial could be the best approach. If you experience some trouble with specific code, don't hesitate to ask stackoverflow community.